# Use an xml file as a rule set for SonarLint (no SonarQube server) in a Eclipse Java environment

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Is it possible to use a rule set defined in .Xml (based on SonarQube- und  FindBugs rules) and run it without setting up a SonarQube server.
I want to use SonarLint in Eclipse for some Java projects with only the input of the rule set i get forwarded from other projects of the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SonarLint standalone - in which case you will get the default, non-editable rule set - or connected to your SonarQube server - in which case you will get the rules in the profile that's applied to your project.

There is no middle ground where you could feed a list of rules in standalone mode.